# Qtip is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

This is probably a really simple solution. But, I am new to jquery, and qtip. For the life of me I cannot get my qtip to show up. All that is shown is the default tooltip. Anyone know what could be the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.qtip.min.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('a[title]').qtip()
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a title="why wont this tooltip work" href ="#">Hello there punk
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a simple example that wont work, any suggestions?

Comment: Always use a `document.ready` function with your jQuery.  Otherwise, your code fails because the HTML did not exist yet when you called `.qtip()`.  Read more:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Ohh okay thank you for informing me on that and providing the link. I have a long way to go learning jQuery! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the docs i think this is the way to do
and this should be called only after document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('body a[href]').qtip();
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct but your brackets are wrong.  It's closed with a `});` and not a `}`.

Comment: @Sparky ya i just forgot 10x.